# CSS drop-down menu links require TWO clicks in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I have a typical CSS site menu/sub-menu system on a site I built. When viewed in Chrome (latest version, on Windows), each link in each sub-menu requires TWO clicks for the link to work. The first click appears to do nothing at all.  It's fine in all other browsers.

I have pared the code down to the minimum that demonstrates the behaviour.  You can see the result here:  https://www.harmonysite.com/chrome-issue.htm  Clicking on the "Sub-menu item" link does nothing in Chrome - the FIRST time.  Click it a second time and it works as expected.  In other browsers it works the first time.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Chrome 59 norepo

Comment: Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) . Seems normal. Single click forwards to next page.

Comment: Same with the v62 Canary. It's just a link, isn't it?

Comment: Odd.  I'm running "Version 61.0.3163.25 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)". I tried turning off all extensions. Made no difference. Single-click on that link does NOTHING the first time. Second time it works.

Comment: On a colleague's computer it works fine.  I can't explain it.  Let's mark this as closed.  FML